# Count the number of entries inside each refsection in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I am formatting my publications in LaTeX. Below is the content of the main file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{publications.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Publications}
\subsection{Journal Articles (1)}
\begin{refsection}
  \nocite{journal1}
  \printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{refsection}

\subsection{Conference Articles (3)}
\begin{refsection}
  \nocite{conference1}
  \nocite{conference2}
  \nocite{conference3}
  \printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

Below is the sample of bibliography:

```
@article{journal1,
  author  = {Author 1},
  title   = {Title 1},
  journal = {Journal 1},
  year    = 1993,
  number  = 2,
  pages   = {201-213},
  month   = 7,
  volume  = 4
}
@inproceedings{conference1,
  title        = {Title 1},
  year         = 1993,
  author       = {Author 1},
  volume       = 4,
  series       = 5,
  address      = {Address 1},
  month        = 7,
  organization = {Organization 1},
  publisher    = {Publisher 1},
}
@inproceedings{conference2,
  title        = {Title 2},
  year         = 1993,
  author       = {Author 2},
  volume       = 4,
  series       = 5,
  address      = {Address 2},
  month        = 7,
  organization = {Organization 2},
  publisher    = {Publisher 2},
}
@inproceedings{conference3,
  title        = {Title 3},
  year         = 1993,
  author       = {Author 3},
  volume       = 4,
  series       = 5,
  address      = {Address 3},
  month        = 7,
  organization = {Organization 3},
  publisher    = {Publisher 3},
}
```

This code generates the following PDF:

[image]

Please notice, I have manually mentioned `\subsection{Journal Articles (1)}` and `\subsection{Conference Articles (3)}`.

What is a good way to count the number of entries inside each `refsection`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can count the number of entries per `refsection` by hooking into `\AtDataInput`. In this solution we create a counter for each section. `\refsectionbibcount` is just a convenient hook to retrieve the counter for the current `refsection`. Note that this solution requires that the heading be typeset *inside* the relevant `refsection`, but that is no problem here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\AtDataInput{%
  \ifltxcounter{datacount@\the\c@refsection}
    {}
    {\newcounter{datacount@\the\c@refsection}}%
  \stepcounter{datacount@\the\c@refsection}}

\newcommand*{\refsectionbibcount}{\arabic{datacount@\the\c@refsection}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{journal1,
  author  = {Author 1},
  title   = {Title 1},
  journal = {Journal 1},
  year    = 1993,
  number  = 2,
  pages   = {201-213},
  month   = 7,
  volume  = 4
}
@inproceedings{conference1,
  title        = {Title 1},
  year         = 1993,
  author       = {Author 1},
  volume       = 4,
  series       = 5,
  address      = {Address 1},
  month        = 7,
  organization = {Organization 1},
  publisher    = {Publisher 1},
}
@inproceedings{conference2,
  title        = {Title 2},
  year         = 1993,
  author       = {Author 2},
  volume       = 4,
  series       = 5,
  address      = {Address 2},
  month        = 7,
  organization = {Organization 2},
  publisher    = {Publisher 2},
}
@inproceedings{conference3,
  title        = {Title 3},
  year         = 1993,
  author       = {Author 3},
  volume       = 4,
  series       = 5,
  address      = {Address 3},
  month        = 7,
  organization = {Organization 3},
  publisher    = {Publisher 3},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbibheading[heading=bibnumbered, title=Publications]
\begin{refsection}
  \nocite{journal1}
  \printbibliography[heading=subbibnumbered, title={Journal Articles (\refsectionbibcount)}]
\end{refsection}
\begin{refsection}
  \nocite{conference1}
  \nocite{conference2}
  \nocite{conference3}
  \printbibliography[heading=subbibnumbered, title={Conference Articles (\refsectionbibcount)}]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

[image: Split bibliography (per type) with number of entries in title]

---

Your use case looks as though you are trying to count per entry type and not per `refsection`, that is also possible. Since you can split your bibliography by type without resorting to `refsections` things are a bit simpler here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\AtDataInput{%
  \ifltxcounter{entrycount@\thefield{entrytype}}
    {}
    {\newcounter{entrycount@\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \stepcounter{entrycount@\thefield{entrytype}}}

\newcommand*{\entrycount}[1]{\arabic{entrycount@#1}}

\newcommand*{\printtypebib}[2]{%
  \printbibliography[type=#1, title={#2 (\entrycount{#1})},
    heading=subbibnumbered]
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{journal1,
  author  = {Author 1},
  title   = {Title 1},
  journal = {Journal 1},
  year    = 1993,
  number  = 2,
  pages   = {201-213},
  month   = 7,
  volume  = 4
}
@inproceedings{conference1,
  title        = {Title 1},
  year         = 1993,
  author       = {Author 1},
  volume       = 4,
  series       = 5,
  address      = {Address 1},
  month        = 7,
  organization = {Organization 1},
  publisher    = {Publisher 1},
}
@inproceedings{conference2,
  title        = {Title 2},
  year         = 1993,
  author       = {Author 2},
  volume       = 4,
  series       = 5,
  address      = {Address 2},
  month        = 7,
  organization = {Organization 2},
  publisher    = {Publisher 2},
}
@inproceedings{conference3,
  title        = {Title 3},
  year         = 1993,
  author       = {Author 3},
  volume       = 4,
  series       = 5,
  address      = {Address 3},
  month        = 7,
  organization = {Organization 3},
  publisher    = {Publisher 3},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibheading[heading=bibnumbered, title=Publications]
\printtypebib{article}{Journal Articles}
\printtypebib{inproceedings}{Conference Articles}
\end{document}
```

[image: Split bibliography (per type) with number of entries in title]

---

Note that since we use `\AtDataInput` in both solutions, the count could be off in case the bibliography is filtered by additional criteria or there are some entries in the `.bbl` that are excluded from the bibliography. It should be possible to guard against these cases, but  what needs to happen may depend on the situation at hand.

Comment: It works. However, the publications are a part of my resume in which I have defined styles for each section. This is why I mentioned `\printbibliography[heading=none]` and used `subsection{Journal Articles (1)}` to write the heading. In realty, it is `mysubsection{Journal Articles (1)}`. I tried changing `heading` to `none` and `subsection{Journal Articles (\refsectionbibcount)}` but it throws error. I guess the macro can't be accessed outside its limited scope.

Comment: @RaviJoshi Yes, as I wrote the macro must be accessed *within* the relevant `refsection`. You can say something like `\defbibheading{bibnumbered}[\refname]{\mysubsection{#1}}` to use `\mysubsection` instead of `\subsection` for the automatic headings. If you can't get that to work for whatever reason, it should be enough to say `heading=none` and move the call to `\mysubsubsection` *inside* the `\begin{refsection}...\end{refsection}`.

Comment: Thank you again for the workaround. Can you please demonstrate how to use `\defbibheading` in this scenario?

Comment: @RaviJoshi Assuming `\mysubsection` works like `\subsection` you'd just write `\defbibheading{subbibnumbered}[\refname]{\mysubsection{#1}}` (I mistakenly put `bibnumbered` in the last comment, you'd probably want to say `\defbibheading{bibnumbered}[\refname]{\mysection{#1}}` for that) into your preamble and continue using the rest of the code as shown in the answer.

Comment: Both solutions are working like a charm. Sincere thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There is the lovely `xcntperchap` package to do exactly this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{publications.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{publications.bib}
@article{journal1,
  author  = {Author 1},
  title   = {Title 1},
  journal = {Journal 1},
  year    = 1993,
  number  = 2,
  pages   = {201-213},
  month   = 7,
  volume  = 4
}
@inproceedings{conference1,
  title        = {Title 1},
  year         = 1993,
  author       = {Author 1},
  volume       = 4,
  series       = 5,
  address      = {Address 1},
  month        = 7,
  organization = {Organization 1},
  publisher    = {Publisher 1},
}
@inproceedings{conference2,
  title        = {Title 2},
  year         = 1993,
  author       = {Author 2},
  volume       = 4,
  series       = 5,
  address      = {Address 2},
  month        = 7,
  organization = {Organization 2},
  publisher    = {Publisher 2},
}
@inproceedings{conference3,
  title        = {Title 3},
  year         = 1993,
  author       = {Author 3},
  volume       = 4,
  series       = 5,
  address      = {Address 3},
  month        = 7,
  organization = {Organization 3},
  publisher    = {Publisher 3},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\newcounter{foo}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\stepcounter{foo}\finentry}
\usepackage{xcntperchap}
\RegisterTrackCounter{subsection}{foo}

\begin{document}
\section{Publications}
\subsection{Journal Articles (\ObtainTrackedValueExp{subsection}{foo})}
\begin{refsection}
    \setcounter{foo}{0}
  \nocite{journal1}
  \printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{refsection}

\subsection{Conference Articles (\ObtainTrackedValueExp{subsection}{foo})}
\begin{refsection}
    \setcounter{foo}{0}
  \nocite{conference1}
  \nocite{conference2}
  \nocite{conference3}
  \printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. The package [xcntperchap](https://ctan.org/pkg/xcntperchap?lang=en) is cool. I will use it in future for tracking the number of subsections etc.